# Can multiple requests affect users in one single IIS instance?

Tags: asp.net, request, instance, iis-10

I'm having a problem on my application. It's an ASP.NET application set up on IIS 10.

Let's say one system page is accessible by 20 users. The page works perfectly (no logical error on coding) every action works and delivers the expected values requested by users.

The problem is, whenever someone requests let's say, the same *method* as another user at the same time (with different values), the application randomly throws an error to one of these users. We've checked for log errors and all of them are system index out of range errors, which never happened in our QA server.

I randomly thought about testing that exact scenario (adding different values with another user at the same time) and I saw it happen for the first time on the QA server. We've managed to reproduce the error multiple times.

While we don't discard the possibility that this could be another issue, did anyone else experience something like that?

The question is: Can IIS manage the *same requests, multiple times at the same time within the same instance* without any trouble? Does it run on multiple threads or something like that?

Thanks for taking time for answering this, if you need any info

Comment: Yes, IIS can handle it fine. Wouldn't be much of a web server if it couldn't. Sounds like there's a bug in your web application.

Comment: Such exceptions are often caused by badly written code where the developers didn't put multithreading into consideration. For instance, classes from `System.Collections.Generics` are not thread safe, so proper locking is required for adding/deleting operations.

Comment: If you post a question with a segment of your code that reproduces the error than there are many on here than can help.

However I agree with @lexLi that you are using a collection which is being shared across the thread which is not thread-safe. Perhap you create this in Global.asax and use it all over.

You will need to look into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/

Answer (score 0):

Stick to your question 
**Yes IIS can handle very easily (more efficient as well)** 
As per your application concern without code I can't point out but you may consider few points

1. Is it happening for just one method or for all. If it happening for just one that means you are trying to use such a code that may used by another user
2. You are using such a array or list which is null or empty for other user. Like a user has First Name Followed by **Last Name** But other user don't fill last name and you are using that last name property
3. May be u r using HttpContext and trying to use same as for different users
4. May be You are using types which are not **Thread safe**

   So these can be possible cases but without code we can't assume.

Answer (score 0):

About your problem, for multiple requests from different user, iis will create a thread in the application pool for each request. For multiple requests from the same user, it will only run in one thread and affect only the user's instance. Unless the instance or resource is a shared resource and your code does not perform any lock operations.

IIS, including most web servers, use threads to process requests, so multiple requests will be executed in parallel unless you place a lock. A web server usually has a minimum and a maximum number of work programs. These work programs are adjusted according to the CPU or memory of the current hardware. If resources are exhausted, new requests will be queued until new resources are available.

So what you need to do may be to modify the application code to take multi-threading and synchronization into consideration.